# Why are Ajax calls giving connection refused error in heroku deployment but working fine with localhost?

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, heroku

i have built a node app with mongodb , when i run it with localhost , all ajax requests are being made, and json object is returned successfully too, but when i deployed the app to heroku , all of the ajax calls give error , for example :

unreviewedposts:98 GET http://localhost:3000/approvepostbyadmin/be3 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

this ajax call is made by clicking the button :

```
  <button id="approve" getpost= "be3"  role="admin" onclick="approveFunc(this)">approve this post and send to respective posts page</button>
```

and here is the script :

```
<script>
      
 
  var httpRequest;
  var status = document.querySelector('#reviewstatus');
  var test; 
  function approveFunc(e){
      curPostSlug = e.getAttribute('getpost');           
      console.log(curPostSlug);
      httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      if (!httpRequest) {
        alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
        return false;
      }
      httpRequest.onreadystatechange = approveFuncRequest;
      httpRequest.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/approvepostbyadmin/'+ curPostSlug);
      httpRequest.send();
    }
    function approveFuncRequest(){
      if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (httpRequest.status === 200 ) {
          var resJson = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText)
          console.log(resJson.reviewed)
          status.innerHTML = "resJson.reviewed"
        } else {
          alert('There was a problem with the request.');
        }
      } else {
        console.log("not ready")
      }
    }
<script>
```

This is just one place, it's giving same eroor for all of my ajax requests on all pages whereever i have used them.
The browser is showing error at httpRequest.send().

What could be the reason behind it ,i have set all env variables correctly, is it because i am using localhost:3000 in the request URL's, if yes what should i use there.
How can i get it to work, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't use localhost there, you need to use a valid hostname for the endpoint

Comment: which hostname i have to use. from where could i find it?@michelem

Comment: I don't know what you have to do there, it could be the Heroku hostname you choose for your project, but only you know where that call should point...